Can I omit 'мы' if the verb ends with '-ем'?
I learned that the pronoun 'мы' matches with verb ending '-ем'
Днём мы работаем, а вечером изучаем испанский.

Then, can I omit the subject 'мы' in the above sentence?
Днём работаем, а вечером изучаем испанский.

Is it grammatically correct and natural?

Short answer is "yes, you can".
Long answer is "it depends, Russian isn't a 'full pro-drop' language, so it will have consequences for information structure". The omitted version is more natural if мы is already established as the topic by context, it is a bit weird (although not strictly incorrect) if used "out of the blue".

If used with no previous context established, it sounds a bit imperative to me. Like an order, or a plan.

@IgorG or a slogan/motto (especially if "а" is omitted).

@DanM. slogan\motto traditionally is an imperative. At least it should be to be a good slogan. The term motto  often meant the words written on heraldic crests and these tend to be imperative absolutes, that should be taken in account in translation (it's a common nadmozg mistake not to do that).

@Swift add an ! at the end of the sentence and it'd totally read like one. Like "Work during the day, learn in the evening!"

It's an elliptical construction, the former variant looks like a gapping ellipsis, while the latter is either an answer ellipsis (and one can argue that I used a form of ellipsis in this phrase, can you see it?) or an imperative meaning "We shall\should".
They exist in English too, but they are less common, probably, because modern English does't have grammatical cases. Russian supports practically all forms of ellipsis, at least in dialog. You wouldn't find much of that in a formal speech or technical text for undestandable reason: it's harder to translate or read out of context.
The case of verb used plays role of hinting which personal pronoun is omitted, in your example it's plural first person. It doesn't hint at any auxilary, so it's unclear if it's an answer\statement (the question was  "What is our schedule?") or a proposal\an order (the question was "What shall we do?"), but content of the statement heavily supports the former.
